# Silence curl with >/dev/null 2>&1 when it's piped

Tags: pipe, curl

So I have a `curl` that is piped to a `grep` and a `sed`.
Where would I apply the `>/dev/null 2>&1` ?

```
curl www.site.com | grep stuff | sed "other stuff"
```

At the very end or after the curl?

Comment: As I said, I want to silence the curl by directing its stdout output and stderr output to /dev/null.

Answer (score 8):

Please be more specific what is the purpose of the command. 
I guess you want to use

```
curl -s www.site.com
```

to prevent the progress indication and other stuff. -s will perform the same action but silently

If you absolutely have to use >/dev/null 2>&1 i think i would redirect curl output to the file

```
curl www.site.com -o file.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
cat file.txt | grep stuff | sed "other stuff"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to achieve. So out of curiousity: Where would the >/dev/null 2>&1 go?

Comment: if you do curl www.site.com >/dev/null 2>&1 | grep stuff | sed "other stuff"
the grep will receive nothing. If you do curl www.site.com >/dev/null 2>&1 | grep stuff | sed "other stuff" >/dev/null 2>&1
you will not see anything.

Answer (score 5):

Just explained a bit closer: `>/dev/null` redirects SDTOUT (standard output) to the "black hole", and `2>&1` appends STDERR (standard error output) to STDOUT so it also goes to Nirvana. This leaves nothing to display: normal output as well as errors are gone. So what you probably *may* want could be

```
curl -s www.site.com 2>/dev/null | grep stuff | sed "other stuff"
```

i.e. not redirecting STDOUT, just suppressing STDERR and telling curl to only show the indended content, then piping that to grep and finally to sed.

Take care to **not** introduce spaces between "2>", or the 2 would rather be interpreted as additional parameter to curl ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across something similar recently and needed to time how long it took to load a particular page. I just used `/dev/null` as my output file and which let me get all the nice stats without printing any of the HTML.

```
curl www.google.com -o /dev/null
```

For my self, I also wrapped it in the `time` command for extra data

```
time (curl www.google.com -o /dev/null)
```

Answer (score -1):

`curl -sw '%{http_code}' www.example.com | tail -n 1`

I prefer this in case the page returns text which sometimes happens, for example when curling a MongoDB driver port.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question, which is about redirecting output to `/dev/null` and piping through `grep`?